# Find files with certain string in specific directories and replace

Tags: bash, find

I have a folder structure like so.

```
.
└── apps/
    ├── bo/
    │   └── platform/
    │       └── values-dev.yaml
    ├── canary/
    │   └── platform/
    │       └── values-canary-dev.yaml
    ├── foo/
    │   ├── customer
    │   ├── audit
    │   ├── platform/
    │   │   └── values-foo-dev.yaml
    │   └── platform-gb/
    │       └── values-foo-dev.yaml
    └── bar/
        ├── customer
        ├── audit
        ├── platform/
        │   └── values-bar-dev.yaml
        ├── platform-usa/
        │   └── values-bar-dev.yaml
        ├── platform-ca/
        │   └── values-bar-dev.yaml
        └── platform-ie/
            └── values-bar-dev.yaml
```

Sorry in advance for the wording.

I'm trying to use `bash` to find and replace specific string `puppy` which exists in each of the `values-*-dev.yaml` files *but* I only want to change it on files which exist under `foo` and `bar` as well as in each `platform` subdirectory and replace `dog` with `dog`

The closest I've gotten is with the following which lists only the files inside `foo` but for the life of me I cannot figure this out.

```shell
find . -type f -path '*foo/platform*' -name 'values-*-dev.yaml'
```

I thought by wrapping `foo` in brackets and adding `bar` it would work but it doesn't

```shell
find . -type f -path '*(foo|bar)/platform*' -name 'values-*-dev.yaml'
```

Comment: `find` accepts a list of start points. If your directory structure is fixed, you can just start with `find apps/{foo,bar}/platform ...` and omit the `-path` option.

Answer (score 1):

No, `find`'s `-name` and `-path` only support basic sh wildcard patterns, so only `?` for single character `*` for any number of characters and `[...]` for single character in a range/set/class (and `\` to escape those)...

Here, with standard `find`, you'd do

```
find . '(' -path '*/foo/platform*' -o -path '*/bar/platform*' ')' \
       -name 'values-*-dev.yaml' \
       -type f \
        -exec perl -pi -e 's/puppy/dog/g' {} +
```

Some `find` implementations also support a `-regex` predicate to match full paths using regexps. For *extended* regexps, on BSDs, you use the `-E` option like for grep/sed and with GNU `find`, the `-regextype posix-extended` "option predicate".

For all variants, regexps are implicitly anchored so you need:

```
# BSD
find -E . -regex '.*/(foo|bar)/platform.*' \
          -name 'values-*-dev.yaml' \
          -type f \
          -exec perl -pi -e 's/puppy/dog/g' {} +
```

```
# GNU
find . -regextype posix-extended \
       -regex '.*/(foo|bar)/platform.*' \
       -name 'values-*-dev.yaml' \
       -type f \
       -exec perl -pi -e 's/puppy/dog/g' {} +
```

Or you could use `zsh`, where that would just be:

```
perl -pi -e 's/puppy/dog/g' -- **/(foo|bar)/platform*/**/values-*-dev.yaml(.)
```

As zsh has several useful glob pattern extensions over the basic sh ones including:

- `**/` which matches any level of subdirectories
- `(a|b)`: alternation like in extended regexps.
- glob qualifiers including `.` used here to restrict the search to *regular* files (equivalent of `find`'s `-type f`).

Comment: Thank you the only thing that seems to be failing is detecting directories which are like `platform-usa` etc.

Comment: @doug, my bad, I had overlooked those. See edit.